# Breaking down raw byte string with particular structure gives wrong data

Tags: c, memory, arm, structure, cortex-m

I am working with one ZigBee module based on 32-bit ARM Cortex-M3. But my question is not related to ZigBee protocol itself. I have access to the source code of application layer only which should be enough for my purposes. Lower layer (APS) passes data to application layer within APSDE-DATA.indication primitive to the following application function:

```
void zbpro_dataRcvdHandler(zbpro_dataInd_t *data)
{
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"\n[APSDE-DATA.indication]\r\n");

    /* Output of raw bytes string for further investigation.
    *  Real length is unknown, 50 is approximation.
    */
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Raw data: \n");
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"----------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"%02x ",*((uint8_t*)data+i));
    }
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"\n");

    /* Output of APSDE-DATA.indication primitive field by field */
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Field by field: \n");
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"----------------\n");
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Destination address: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"%02x ",*((uint8_t*)data->dstAddress.ieeeAddr[i]));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"\n");
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Destination address mode: 0x%02x\r\n",*((uint8_t*)data->dstAddrMode));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Destination endpoint: 0x%02x\r\n",*((uint8_t*)data->dstEndPoint));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Source address mode: 0x%02x\r\n",*((uint8_t*)data->dstAddrMode));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Source address: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"%02x ",*((uint8_t*)data->srcAddress.ieeeAddr[i]));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"\n");
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Source endpoint: 0x%02x\r\n",*((uint8_t*)data->srcEndPoint));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Profile Id: 0x%04x\r\n",*((uint16_t*)data->profileId));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Cluster Id: 0x%04x\r\n",*((uint16_t*)data->clusterId));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Message length: 0x%02x\r\n",*((uint8_t*)data->messageLength));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Flags: 0x%02x\r\n",*((uint8_t*)data->flags));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Security status: 0x%02x\r\n",*((uint8_t*)data->securityStatus));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Link quality: 0x%02x\r\n",*((uint8_t*)data->linkQuality));
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Source MAC Address: 0x%04x\r\n",*((uint16_t*)data->messageLength));    
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"Message: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++){
        DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"%02x ",*((uint8_t*)data->messageContents+i));
    }
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"\n");

    bufm_deallocateBuffer((uint8_t *)data, CORE_MEM);
}
```

APSDE-DATA.indication primitive is implemented by following structures:

```
/**
 *  @brief type definition for address (union of short address and extended address)
 */
typedef union zbpro_address_tag {
    uint16_t shortAddr;
    uint8_t ieeeAddr[8];
} zbpro_address_t;

/**
 *  @brief apsde data indication structure
 */
PACKED struct zbpro_dataInd_tag {
    zbpro_address_t dstAddress;
    uint8_t dstAddrMode;
    uint8_t dstEndPoint;
    uint8_t srcAddrMode;
    zbpro_address_t srcAddress;
    uint8_t srcEndPoint;
    uint16_t profileId;
    uint16_t clusterId;
    uint8_t messageLength;
    uint8_t flags; /* bit0: broadcast or not; bit1: need aps ack or not; bit2: nwk key used; bit3: aps link key used */
    uint8_t securityStatus; /* not-used, reserved for future */
    uint8_t linkQuality;
    uint16_t src_mac_addr;
    uint8_t messageContents[1];
};
typedef PACKED struct zbpro_dataInd_tag zbpro_dataInd_t;
```

As a result I receive next:

```
[APSDE-DATA.indication]

Raw data:
---------
00 00 00 72 4c 19 40 00 02 e8 03 c2 30 02 fe ff 83 0a 00 e8 05 c1 11 00 11 08 58 40 72 4c ae 53 4d 3f 63 9f d8 51 da ca 87 a9 0b b3 7b 04 68 ca 87 a9

Field by field:
---------------
Destination address: 00 00 00 28 fa 44 34 00
Destination address mode: 0x12
Destination endpoint: 0xc2
Source address mode: 0x12
Source address: 13 01 12 07 02 bd 02 00
Source endpoint: 0xc2
Profile Id: 0xc940
Cluster Id: 0x90a0
Message length: 0x00
Flags: 0x00
Security status: 0x04
Link quality: 0x34
Source MAC Address: 0x90a0
Message: ae 53 4d 3f 63 9f d8 51 da ca 87 a9 0b
```

From this output I can see that while raw string has some expected values, dispatched fields are totally different. What is the reason of this behavior and how to fix it? Is it somehow related to ARM architecture or wrong type casting?

I don't have access to implementation of DEBUG_PRINT, but we can assume that it works properly.

Comment: `data->dstAddrMode` (and most everything else in your struct) is *not* an address. It is actually an `uint8_t`. Casting `uint8_t` to `uint8_t*` doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to dereference in your DEBUG_PRINT statements, for example

```
DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"%02x ",*((uint8_t*)data->dstAddress.ieeeAddr[i]));
```

should be simply

```
DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"%02x ", data->dstAddress.ieeeAddr[i]);
```

so on and so forth...

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
    DEBUG_PRINT(DBG_APP,"%02x ",*((uint8_t*)data->dstAddress.ieeeAddr[i]));
```

Array subscripting and direct and indirect member access have higher precedence than does casting, so the third argument is equivalent to

```
*( (uint8_t*) (data->dstAddress.ieeeAddr[i]) )
```

But `data->dstAddress.ieeeAddr[i]` is not a pointer, it is an `uint8_t`.  C permits you to convert it to a pointer by casting, but the result is not a pointer *to* the value, but rather a pointer interpretation *of* the value.  Dereferencing it produces undefined behavior.

Similar applies to your other `DEBUG_PRINT()` calls.